# Monitor turns off when I unplug from AC power, how do I stop this?

Tags: 11.04, macbook, backlight, pommed

I'm running natty on a 13" macbook pro, and when I unplug the AC power sometimes, the monitor turns off. Sometimes I can unplug the AC adapter and nothing happens, but as soon as it starts happening it happens every time I unplug. When I plug the adapter back in, the monitor comes back.

Comment: Is it really off or just at the lowest brightness setting?

Comment: start a sound file, and unplug AC, the music still played?

Comment: It's really off, it's like the backlight gets turned off. I'm thinking it's a bug in pommed. When I kill pommed, it's not a problem.

Comment: First, remember that Natty is still one of those crazy alpha releases, and they can and do have issues. Second, report the bug by running ubuntu-bug , and answer the questions as best as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Pommed is misconfigured by default to set brightness to 6 (out of 44000) on battery for nvidia. The pommed config file is /etc/pommed.conf, and the section is sysfs_backlight/on_batt. Setting this to a more reasonable, value such as 22000 fixes the issue. You can mess around with values to set it to by running

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/${driver}/max_brightness
$ echo ${0 < brightness < max_brightness} | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/${driver}/brightness
```

Note that's kind of pseudo shell code, the value for driver will probably be the only subdir or backlight, so just hit tab in the shell to autocomplete it, and the value to echo can be whatever you want so long as it's between 0 and max_brightness. Setting to 0 will turn off your backlight so I can't really recommend you do that.